# Стандартные методы шифрования php

Tags: php

Есть ли в `php` - функция для шифрования строк в `HEX` представление ? Именно шифрования а не хеширования, функция должна быть обратимой. При этом количество входных данных непостоянно, строка может быть из 5-15 символов но `HEX` представление наоборот фиксированным, что то вроде

> `mysendingparam` -> `1a21a22c3802c380`
>
> `112233` -> `8a21aff3802c323`.

Не хочется писать велосипед, наверняка в стандартных функциях подобное реализовано.

Comment: https://www.base64encode.net/php-base64-encode - вот такое подойдет?

Comment: HEX-представление не является шифрованием.

Comment: @andreymal я в курсе. Я говорил о том что результат должен быть хекс представление фиксированной длины

Comment: Проголосовал за закрытие. Непонятно зачем писать что не нужны кастыли и самому же их изобретать.

Comment: Вам надо разделить задачу на 2 части: 1 - шифрование (оно работает с бинарными данными), 2 - вывод в шестнадцетиричке. для п.1 можно использовать например http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php для второй pack/unpack (там в примере как раз есть) или другие функции

Comment: @Сергей в таком случае уберите любое упоминание шифрования из вопроса, потому что это лишь запутывает и снижает шансы на получение внятного ответа

Comment: @andreymal зачем убирать про шифрование, если именно про него и вопрос? Человек ищет вариант шифрования, чтобы результат в итоге всегда был представим шестнадцатеричной строкой

Comment: @teran это по-прежнему совершенно непонятно ни из вопроса, ни из комментариев. До сих пор ничего не исправлено — нужно закрывать

Comment: @teran и да, абсолютно любой набор байтов можно представить в виде HEX, так что ваша интерпретация вопроса несколько бессмысленная

Comment: @andreymal речь была про хекс фиксированной длины, не дописал. я к тому, что из вопроса убирать надо часть про хекс а не шифрование

Comment: @teran вообще, получить зашифрованные байты и получить HEX из байтов - это две разные задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точнее задавайте вопросы или формулируйте мысли если это не то

dechex() - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.dechex.php

hexdec() - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hexdec.php

Comment: 'HEX представление наоборот фиксированным'

Comment: Я же говорю, выражайте мысли яснее, 123(DEC) -> HEX всегда будет 7B, фиксировано 7B... =) а если вы таки про размер, то так и говорите что хотите **фиксированной длинны** или **фиксированного размера**

Comment: можете дополнить незначащую часть с лева нулями, и тогда длинна будет фиксирована str_pad, если очень хочется заполнять мусором можно например использовать формат: **{Размер числа (5-15 хватит 1 байта в HEX)}[МУСОР]{Нужное число}** всё это можно реализовать парой функций....

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/295848)

Comment: @Naumov так лучше?

Answer (score 0):

Присмотрись ты и к этим функциям.Тут длина шестнадцатеричного представления зависит от длины строки:

```
bin2hex(str);
```

А эта функция декодирует строку данных из шестнадцатеричного представления:

```
hex2bin(str);
```